# Slack API throwing KeyError with Slack Token

Tags: python, slack, slack-api

So I've been trying to make a slack bot and have the following code run to make sure everything is working fine, just been following a video, but VS Code is giving me a key error. I'm using a virtual environment, activated with the right libraries installed. I've used both slackclient and slack_sdk packages and I am still getting the same error. I have looked up similar questions and I have the most updated version of the libraries, installed and uninstalled multiple times to no avail. SLACK_TOKEN is in a .env file in the same directory. Any clue as to why I am getting this error?

```
import dotenv
import os
from slack_sdk import WebClient
from pathlib import Path
from dotenv import load_dotenv
import slack_sdk

env_path = Path('.')/ '.env'
load_dotenv(dotenv_path=env_path)

client = WebClient(token=os.environ['SLACK_TOKEN'])
```

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem with the code you've shared.  Is the `.env` file not in the place you expect it to be?  What output do you get if you add the line `print(env_path.absolute())`?

Comment: The path looks to be right. **Output** is `C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\Project\.env`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code should work and it works for me. You should recheck your `.env` file one more time, maybe you have a typo or incorrect `.env` file format. And if I understand correctly your problem has nothing to do with Slack, the problem with dotenv loading. You can check it by outputting `os.environ._data` dict and checking the keys of this dict.

Comment: The only thing in my `.env` file is the following: `SLACK_TOKEN = my-token`. But what is weird is that I don't have that func

Comment: Could you try to remove spaces in your `.env` like this `SLACK_TOKEN=my-token`?

Comment: I removed the spaces but still getting same KeyError, and I'm sorry the original message got cut off cause I fat fingered the enter button, heres the rest: As for what gets outputted when print `os.environ._data` is a lot but some notable things is that it recognizes the virtual environment but the very last key on the dict is `PYDEVD_USE_FRAME_EVAL': 'NO'` not sure if that's whats causing the issue. Is there a specific key you want me to find? Appreciate the help!

Comment: "Is there a specific key you want me to find" - I wanted you to make sure that there is no key `SLACK_TOKEN` in this dictionary.

Comment: Ok, one more step to determine the problem: could you execute `print(load_dotenv(dotenv_path=env_path))`? If it prints `False`, then problem is definitely with dotenv loading.

Comment: It printed `True`

Comment: And what about the presence of key `SLACK_TOKEN` in the `os.environ._data`?

Comment: And more: how do you run the script? From the repository where is the file located? Could you specify a command? Do you use a virtual environment?

Comment: I use a virtual environment, but I fixed my issue actually like 10 mins ago by just making a new virtual environment, moving my files to that new environment, and reinstalling the same libraries, when I started running it, it went through without a problem. Man, that was troublesome but thanks for your help!

Comment: I'm glad you managed to figure it out!